# What should done about my mistake?

Tags: discussion

A while ago, I asked the question ["How long can a player hold off a draw by the 50-move rule?"](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/32577/how-long-can-a-player-hold-off-a-draw-by-the-50-move-rule/32580#comment50773_32580) However, I forgot a crucial detail in that the prolonging side shouldn't be able to win at any time. Editing the question now would invalidate both answers. What should be done here? I feel that the question should be closed and a new one asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Editing the question now would invalidate both answers.

Exactly, thanks for taking that into consideration.

> I feel that the question should be closed

Why? The question as posed seems to be on-topic.

> and a new one asked.

I feel that's the way to go.